# tty login fails without any error message

Tags: 12.04, login, tty

When I try to log in via `tty` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd>) I get a prompt, e.g.:

```
laboratory login:
```

I can then type in the username and press enter but it immediately resets to the same prompt, with no error message and no password prompt. I am unable to log into my graphical environment, hence needing to use tty (I believe my desktop manager is not starting). What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're probably typing the wrong username: remember that upon user's creation, if the full name provided it's two words long and it contains uppercases (e.g. "John Smith"), it will default to the first word converted to lowercase (i.e. "john").

Before switching to a `tty`, open a terminal within your graphic environment by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run the command `whoami`: this will return the exact username to be used upon `tty` login.

---

Since you can't access your graphical environment, try the following:

1. Shutdown the system
2. While booting, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to access `grub2`'s menu
3. Select `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: grub2-1]

4. Select your current kernel's recovery mode (e.g. `Ubuntu 12.04 x.xx.xx-xx-generic (recovery mode)`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: grub2-2]

5. Select `root - Drop to root shell prompt` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Recovery menu]

6. Run `cat /etc/passwd` to see a list of all the users present in the system. Check your actual username
7. Run `exit`
8. Select `resume - Resume normal boot`
9. Try to login in a `tty` using the username recovered from the list

Comment: I'm unable to get into my desktop environment, hence why I am using the tty in the first place. I am also fairly confident I am using the correct username although I'll look into it. Is there any way using a Live USB that I can determine the correct username to input?

Comment: @Birdie Yes there is, and there's also a faster method. I can write an answer for that, but the fastest way overall would be to just try to insert the first word of your username converted to lowercase, because that is usually the correct username to be used

Comment: The username is only one word anyway, and it's lowercase as well.

Comment: @Birdie Ok, please add that you can't login to your graphic environment to your original question, in the meantime I'll write another answer

Comment: @Birdie Check the update on this answer

Comment: @Birdie: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the abysmally small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: @kos the username I found was the same one that I had been trying, so I am still unable to log in via tty.

Answer (score 1):

the workaround is to append somewhere in your kernel cmdline while in grub the parameter `init=/bin/bash` or /bin/sh or zsh whatever you use. also change ro to rw otherwise you need to `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdx /`. do not forget to # out whatever comes after this parameter or append it at the end otherwise it will read the output after as a command in shell.

Comment: It would probably help to say why you believe this will fix it, or how someone could confirm this is the problem? Also, should it be `dash`, isn't that the Ubuntu default shell? Welcome to AU!